# Adding new button to GridLayout Android

Tags: java, android, button, gridview, android-gridlayout

can I add new buttons to the GridLayout in Android app?

Like in Java:

```
JButton buttons[]={button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7,button8,button9,button10,button11,button12, button13,button14,button15,button16,button17,button18,button19,button20,button21,button22,button23,button24};
...

for(int i=0; i<24;i++)
window.add(buttons[i]);
```

Is it possible to do something similiar in Android? Because I want to place my buttons in 4x6 grid in random place. I did it with simple Java, but I do not know how to make it in Android. Or maybe I should use GridView?

**EDIT:** It is the code in java (no Android):

```
private JFrame window = new JFrame("Name");
...
private JButton buttons[]={button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7,button8,button9,button10,button11,button12,      button13,button14,button15,button16,button17,button18,button19,button20,button21,button22,button23,button24};
...
for(i=0;i<24;i++)
window.add(buttons[i]);
...
```

How will it look in Android?

Comment: Why don't you try using GridView first and come back when you have tried it for a while with a more specific question if you run in to problems? It seems like you know half the answer to your question already.

Comment: Of course it is possible,there is a GridLayout in android similar to swing in Java.

Comment: GridView will be the right choice for your requirement as @SimonAndréForsberg said.

Comment: Ok, I will try with GridView, but before, mohammad sadegh saati, can you show me beginning of the code in java file if I will use GridLayout? Check my edit in the question.